# Regexp to check if code contains non-UTF-8 characters?

Tags: java, regex, utf-8, sonarqube

I am using PMD, checkstyle, findbugs, etc. in Sonar. I would like to have a rule verifying that Java code contains no characters not part of UTF-8.

E.g. the character � should not be allowed

I could not find a rule for this in the above plugins, but I guess a custom rule can be made in Sonar.

Comment: So you're looking for invalid UTF-8 byte sequences?

Comment: "�" *is* a perfectly valid Unicode character with a valid UTF-8 byte sequence... What you want is to validate the encoding, which is a pretty long regex, but easy for a tool that checks encodings.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8

Comment: ""�" is a perfectly valid Unicode character with a valid UTF-8 byte sequence" really? I thought it would not because my Java compiler gives "warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8"

Comment: No no, "�" is the Unicode replacement character. We are typing it here, so it's a perfectly valid character. Any *byte sequence* that a UTF-8 decoder cannot recognize as valid UTF-8 will be replaced by that character though. So you don't want to check for "invalid characters", but for *invalid byte sequences*.

Comment: " but for invalid byte sequences" can this be found during static analysis? The way I see it, when a "�" character is found the damage is already done...

Comment: @user You need to distinguish between a file being parsed with invalid UTF-8 sequences being replaced by "�" on the fly for display and a file having a "�" character hardcoded in it. In the former case, the "�" is not actually in the file, it is just being rendered as a sign of "invalid UTF-8". In the latter case, the file may be perfectly valid UTF-8, simply with the "�" character in it. What you want is to check if the encoding is valid, not whether there's a "�" character in it. I don't know how to do this with the tools you mention, but a CLI utility like `iconv` should do it.

Comment: @wvxvw Yes, be careful with that word. :P UTF-7 uses only 7 bits, but is *not* ASCII **compatible**. It's compatible with transfer agents which only support 7-bit, but it's something entirely different than ASCII. ASCII uses all combinations of 7 bit = 128 code points. Something which also uses only 7 bit *and* uses all the same code point mappings as ASCII is simply the same as ASCII and there's no room for anything else.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the regular expression which will match only valid UTF-8 byte sequences:

```
/^([\x00-\x7F]|[\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|\xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE1-\xEC][\x80-\xBF]{2}|\xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]|[\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}|\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2})*$/
```

I have derived it from [RFC 3629 UTF-8, a transformation format of ISO 10646](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt) section 4 -  Syntax of UTF-8 Byte Sequences.

Factorizing the above gives the slightly shorter:

```
/^([\x00-\x7F]|([\xC2-\xDF]|\xE0[\xA0-\xBF]|\xED[\x80-\x9F]|(|[\xE1-\xEC]|[\xEE-\xEF]|\xF0[\x90-\xBF]|\xF4[\x80-\x8F]|[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF])[\x80-\xBF])[\x80-\xBF])*$/
```

This simple perl script demonstrates usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $passstring = "This string \xEF\xBF\xBD == � is valid UTF-8";
my $failstring = "This string \x{FFFD} == � is not valid UTF-8";
if ($passstring =~ /^([\x00-\x7F]|[\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|\xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE1-\xEC][\x80-\xBF]{2}|\xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]|[\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}|\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2})*$/)
    {
    print 'Passstring passed'."\n";
    }
else
    {
    print 'Passstring did not pass'."\n";
    }
if ($failstring =~ /^([\x00-\x7F]|[\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|\xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE1-\xEC][\x80-\xBF]{2}|\xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]|[\xEE-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}|\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2})*$/)
    {
    print 'Failstring passed'."\n";
    }
else
    {
    print 'Failstring did not pass'."\n";
    }
exit;
```

It produces the following output:

```
Passstring passed
Failstring did not pass
```

Comment: This regex fails for characters with accents like áéíóú. https://regex101.com/r/sRXjej/